# @reboot works with command but not script - Cron

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, scripts, cron, reboot

So I am trying to run a script as a specific user @boot.

I have come across using @reboot in conjunction with crontab.

I have found that @reboot is supported by both the user and root via

```
@reboot echo "hello" > /root/hello.sh
```

and same for a regular user and the hello.sh file appeared after reboot

But if I try (tried both with roots crontab and users crontab)

```
@reboot ~/.reboot.sh
```

or

```
@reboot /home/user/.reboot.sh
```

or

```
@reboot user /home/user/.reboot.sh
```

Nothing!

Also the script works via

```
~/.reboot.sh
```

&

```
/home/user/.reboot.sh
```

in CLI environment. Again this can't be run as root, needs to be run by the user!

[Update]

The specific command I want to run is

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm VMNAME
```

And via crontab this works

```
*/1 * * * * VBoxHeadless --startvm VMNAME
```

But this does not?!

```
@reboot VBoxHeadless --startvm VMNAME
```

[update2]

This works

```
@reboot /home/user/.reboot.sh
```

when .reboot.sh contains

```
echo "hello" > /home/user/hello.sh
```

So this is a problem with the VboxManage command specifically. Perhaps it lags at boot? Any thoughts are appreciated, but I think I need to look into specifically the command VboxManage, tho I did master running command @ boot as a user today! Just found this command didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the vbox modules just isn't available in time of execution.
Why don't you create a service? Refer to corresponding documentation of your init system.

Comment: Yea I finally figured it out, the life of a computer guy, had 2 restart 20 times via process of elimination I figured that out! Thanks tho, I did research about a VboxAutoStart command, but I wanted to mash together mastering running something a boot then I could just edit .reboot.sh but sounds like I need a seperate set up just for Vbox.... I also read that VboxAutoStart isn't installed by default anymore fun times!

Comment: Are you saying like create an init.d script?

Comment: Yes, for example. You just need to correctly handle dependencies, you may enable it for runlevel '5'.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I finished with! [Upstart Script](https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/2015/10/24/autostart-virtualbox-vm-headless-with-upstart-script-ubuntu-server-and-vbox-5/#comment-40)

Comment: NM, It's pleasure for me that I can help you.